# Start exe file on remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I have a process a method that successfully stops the process.  But how can I start it? It is a .exe file that lays on the remote machines harddrive.

```
var ui = new ImpersonateUser();
var processName = "notepad.exe";
object[] processArgs = { @"C:\\WINDOWS\notepad.exe" };

try
    {
        ui.Impersonate(Domain, _userName, _pass);

        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath
        {
            Server = "serverName",
            NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2",
            ClassName = "Win32_Process"
        };

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path);
        ManagementClass management = new ManagementClass(path);

        var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * from Win32_process WHERE name = '" + processName + "'");

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
            {
                process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null); //This work
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                management.InvokeMethod("Create", processArgs); //doesnt work. Why ?
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the .exe start after I have shut it down?

Comment: I hope this will give you an idea. [Creating Process Remotely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389769(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Thangadurai I have updated my answer but it still doesn't work

Comment: Why do you escape the first backslash in your processArgs, but not the second? I'd look in that direction.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Don't really understand what you mean. Have tried all different paths

Comment: @krillezzz Have you tried `@"c:\Windows\notepad.exe"` instead of `@"c:\\Windows\notepad.exe"`? You're using a string literal (the @), which means that the string will be read EXACTLY as you pass it through. You only need one backslash between c: and Windows in that case. If you use 2 backspaces, it tries to go to a directory that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (D instead of T) in a program name. It should be noTepad.exe and not noDepad.exe Besides I suggest to check results returned by *InvokeMethod* In your case it returns 9 what means *Path Not Found*. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) is a full list of codes.

**UPDATE**

If *InvokeMethod* returns 0 but you don't see a new instance of notepad on a remote machine it means that it was run in background. However, you should be able to see this new instance in Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Oh..I changed to notepad but it still didn't work. Will try with return value